# os x python 2.6 bus error

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, macports

i am getting weird python bus error when building a web app.

http://pastie.org/714569

i am using python 2.6 from mac ports in osx snowleopart 10.6.2. i have done python_select and stuff. how to figure out what is going on?
thanks

Comment: Well, you're accessing memory which doesn't belong to you. To determine the cause it would be nice to see the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in Python or your web application framework. Please report it to their respective bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on my MacOS 10.6.8 with both python 2.7.1 and 2.6.1. The problem appeared after a year of successful work. I suspect a system updated was the reason. I upgraded the python framework to 2.7.3 and this helped.